# Why Nightwatch run every .js file as Child process? (Perhaps i have changed some config)

Tags: javascript, selenium-rc

Lately when i run Nightwtch.js , my console run as child process every file .js of every folder or subfolder as Child process. Multiple chrome instances are open with them too. Even module folder with require js libraries.. I think i m forgetting some config.

I only want to run the main Nightwatch js file with one chrome..

My console prints starting..

nightwatch bot.js -c config_chrome.json

Started child process for: tests/extra/assertions/customAssertion 
Started child process for: tests/extra/commands/customCommand

> > tests/extra/assertions/customAssertion finished.
> >
> > tests/extra/commands/customCommand finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/commands/customCommandConstructor 
Started child process for: tests/extra/commands/other/otherCommand

> > tests/extra/commands/customCommandConstructor finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/globals

> > tests/extra/globals finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/otherPageobjects/otherPage

> > tests/extra/otherPageobjects/otherPage finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/pageobjects/SimplePageFn

> > tests/extra/pageobjects/SimplePageFn finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/pageobjects/invalidPageObj

> > tests/extra/commands/other/otherCommand finished.

Started child process for: tests/extra/pageobjects/simplePageObj

> > tests/extra/pageobjects/invalidPageObj finished.

Answer (score 0):

I forget sending --test to console... :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a configuration setting that can cause this behavior as well.

If you've set `"test_workers": true` in `nightwatch.conf.js` all of your tests are run in **parallel**, and this fires up `child processes` for every file in your the directory where `nightwatch` runs its tests.

Documentation here:
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/running-tests/run-parallel.md